# How do I fix apt-get upgrade error due to MsBuild?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I've just run an update on my system, and I have an install error for the msbuild package.

After run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade`, I got this error message:

```
Preparing to Unpack .../msbuild_1%3a16.0+xamarinxplat.2019.05.07.15.32-0xamarin2+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb ... 
Unpacking msbuild (1:16.0+xamarinxplat.2019.05.07.15.32-0xamarin2+ubuntu1804b1) over (1:16.0+xamarinxplat.2018.09.26.17.53-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1) ... 
dpkg: error while processing the file /var/cache/apt/archives/msbuild_1%3a16.0+xamarinxplat.2019.05.07.15.32-0xamarin2+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb (--unpack):
  trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0', which is also in the package mono-roslyn 5.20.1.19-0xamarin2+ubuntu1804b1
Errors were encountered while processing:
  /var/cache/apt/archives/msbuild_1%3a16.0+xamarinxplat.2019.05.07.15.32-0xamarin2+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've also try to install with `sudo dpkg -i --force-depends /var/cache/apt/archives/msbuild_1%3a16.0+xamarinxplat.2019.05.07.15.32-0xamarin2+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb`. Then I got almost the same error message:

```
(Lendo banco de dados ... 230920 ficheiros e directórios actualmente instalados.)
A preparar para desempacotar .../msbuild_1%3a16.0+xamarinxplat.2019.05.07.15.32-0xamarin2+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb ... 
A descompactar msbuild (1:16.0+xamarinxplat.2019.05.07.15.32-0xamarin2+ubuntu1804b1) sobre (1:16.0+xamarinxplat.2018.09.26.17.53-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1) ... 
dpkg: erro ao processar o arquivo /var/cache/apt/archives/msbuild_1%3a16.0+xamarinxplat.2019.05.07.15.32-0xamarin2+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb (--install):
  a tentar sobre-escrever '/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0', que também está no pacote mono-roslyn 5.20.1.19-0xamarin2+ubuntu1804b1
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
  /var/cache/apt/archives/msbuild_1%3a16.0+xamarinxplat.2019.05.07.15.32-0xamarin2+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb
```

Comment: Why don't you use the official dotnet packages?

Comment: I'm using the packages from the [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-ubuntu) repository.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" upgrade
```

fixed it for me

Comment: Short and to the point. Thanks. Fixed my problem :)

Comment: i get this error: 
```text
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/15.0/SolutionFile/ImportAfter': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/15.0/SolutionFile': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/15.0/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore': Directory not empty
```

Comment: @PatrikLaszlo if it doesn't stop the upgrade from completing i'd ignore it

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me on Both on Ubuntu and Debian 10.

This command fixed the issue for me:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" -f install
```

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked in 2 steps:

```
apt upgrade -y
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" upgrade
sudo dpkg -i --force-depends /var/cache/apt/archives/msbuild_1%3a16.0+xamarinxplat.2019.05.07.15.32-0xamarin2+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb
```